# Get HTTP code from org.apache.http.HttpResponse

Tags: java, apache, httpresponse

I'm using the `org.apache.http.HttpResponse` class in my Java application, and I need to be able to get the HTTP status code. If I used `.toString()` on it, I can see the HTTP status code in there. Is there any other function that I can just get the HTTP status code as either an int or String?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Use [`HttpResponse.getStatusLine()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getStatusLine%28%29), which returns a `StatusLine` object containing the status code, protocol version and "reason".

Answer (score 72):

I have used `httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` and have found this to reliably return the integer http status code.

Answer (score 39):

```
httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Answer (score 3):

A example will be as below,

```
        final String enhancementPayload ="sunil kumar";
        HttpPost submitFormReq = new HttpPost("https://bgl-ast/rest/service/form/form-data");
        StringEntity enhancementJson = new StringEntity(enhancementPayload);
        submitFormReq.setEntity(enhancementJson);
        submitFormReq.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute( submitFormReq );
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println("result "+result);
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```