# Automating API's

Tags: api, postman, web-api-testing

> Automating API's:

**How to automate API testing without using any third party tools**?

1. IDE's required? Choice is Eclipse.
2. Java - Choice of programming language.
3. ***Suggest Integration required if any?***
4. ***Suggestions on Framework approach/Methodology required?***
5. ***Reporting Integrations/Ideas required?***

Thank you in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java + jUnit. 
Just [send HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java) and check their response in your test. To make it all as tests use jUnit framework.

Comment: Hi Denis, Appreciate your reply. Could you please  elaborate on sending requests capturing schemas and validating responses?

Comment: I'm not into Java. But I guess this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153283/get-http-code-from-org-apache-http-httpresponse and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467848/how-to-get-http-response-code-for-a-url-in-java will help you. Thanks a lot for marking the answer as the best one!

Comment: :) Thank you for the help !